# What is the quickest way to randomize a data set?

Tags: php

For a multiple choice quiz application i would like to show the dummy answers with the correct answer. But with the correct answer being in a different position at each different question.

This is what i've tried but it doesn't seem to be working:

```
if ($question->type == 1)
            {   

                echo "<div id='dummy_answers'>";
                //Show Dummy
                echo '<h3>Dummy Answers</h3>';
                //Get Dummy Answers
                $query = $this->test_model->getDummyAnswers($question->id);
                $dummy_num = 1;
                foreach ($query->result() as $row)
                {
                    $rand_number = rand(1, 3);
                    if ($dummy_num == $rand_number)
                    {
                        $dummy_num = $rand_number + 2;
                        echo '<h4>Answer '.$dummy_num.'</h4>';
                        echo '<p>';
                        echo $row->option;
                        echo '</p>';
                        //Now echo the real answer
                        echo '<h4>Answer '.$rand_number.'</h4>';
                        echo '<p>';
                        echo $row->option;
                        echo '</p>'; //Get id's for each.echo $row->id;         
                    }
                    else
                    {
                        echo '<h4>Answer '.$dummy_num.'</h4>';
                        echo '<p>';
                        echo $row->option;
                        echo '</p>';
                        $dummy_num++;
                    }
                }
                echo '</div>';
                echo '  <hr/>';
            }
        ?>
```

Comment: I said 'quickest', meant 'best'. :).,

Comment: its always best to look for the best way to do things.

Comment: no. in fact, if you start to look for the "best" way of doing things you will do not a thing actually - you will waste all your time for just looking the best way of looking the best way to do something. While **indeed** the best way is only to look for something only for some **reason**

Comment: On the contrary, looking for the best way both saves time and boosts productivity in the long run. i.e. Using version control (the 'best' way) vs. Not using version control..

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You should use [shuffle function](http://php.net/manual/en/function.shuffle.php).
In your case it will be:

```
if ($question->type == 1)
  { 
    echo "<div id='dummy_answers'>";
    //Show Dummy
    echo '<h3>Dummy Answers</h3>';
    //Get Dummy Answers
    $query = $this->test_model->getDummyAnswers($question->id);
    $answers=$query->result();
    shuffle($answers);
    foreach ($answers as $nr=>$row)
    {
        echo '<h4>Answer '.($nr+1).'</h4>';
        echo '<p>';
        echo $row->option;
        echo '</p>';
    }
    echo '</div>';
    echo '  <hr/>';
  }
?>
```

Answer (score 0):

Put the answers in an array the use [shuffle](http://fr.php.net/manual/en/function.shuffle.php)

```
$random_array = shuffle($answers);
```

Answer (score 0):

You could put the results into an array (1 correct and 3 incorrect), then `shuffle`, then output them?

```
$answers = array();

array_push($answers, "answer1");
array_push($answers, "answer2");
array_push($answers, "answer3");
array_push($answers, "answer4");

shuffle($answers);

foreach ($answers as $answer) {
    echo $answer;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

All you need to do is put the keys for your answers in an array and call [`shuffle()`](http://php.net/shuffle). Something like this:

```
$keys = array_keys($answers);
shuffle($keys);
for ($key in $keys) {
   echo $answers[$key];
}
```

Answer (score 0):

I would suggest putting all the answers into an array and using the `shuffle()` function to randomize them.  Once they're shuffled, just iterate the array with a loop and build the markup.